# ¿Cómo incrementar llave en clave compuesta?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Les comento, estoy trabajando en una base de datos, en la cual se pretende tener un control de revisiones

Poseemos un código comercial único por producto, por lo que al momento de manejar las revisiones existirían dos llaves primarias

Pongo un ejemplo para que quede más clara la situación

```
class Producto
{
   [Key]
   [Column(Order = 0 )]    
   string CodigoComercial { get; set; }

   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Column(Order = 1)]
   string Revision { get; set; }

   string CampoRandom { get; set; }
}
```

Mi problema, se da al incrementar la variable `Revision`.

Pretendo, que para cada `CodigoComercial`, la columna `Revision` incremente desde 1 en adelante, y lo que obtengo, es una columna `Revisión` que incrementa independientemente de lo que se encuentre en `CodigoComercial`

¿Cúal es la mejor opción para llegar a lo que busco?

Sé que existe la opción de contar las filas cuando consulto la base de datos, o tratar el campo `Revision` como no incremental y, previo a agregar el registro, calcular el siguiente número de `Revision` sin embargo ambas alternativas me parecen malas a la hora de pensar en performance a futuro (ya que se trabajaría con *MUCHOS* registros)

Aclaro que trabajo con Entity Framework 6 (Code First), ASP MVC 5 y SQL Server

Comment: "o tratar el campo Revision como no incremental y, previo a agregar el registro, calcular el siguiente número de Revision" porque es mala? es la unica que se me ocurre en tu caso...

Comment: @gbianchi quizás sea un error conceptual mio, pero, teniendo una cantidad muy elevada de registros, realizarle una query extra antes de cualquier modificación me pareció mala práctica, estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: para estos casos lo mejor es un trigger con un procedimiento almacenado que se encargue en cada insert de devolverte la revisión. debes llamar a before insert https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: acá una consulta sobre esto en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458006/how-to-emulate-a-before-insert-trigger-in-t-sql-sql-server-for-super-subtype